How to configure Azure Front Door with Azure API Management (APIM) custom domain without changing the CNAME to APIM?
I’m trying to configure a custom domain for my Azure API Management (APIM) gateway while routing traffic through Azure Front Door.
Here’s my setup:
Custom Domain: api.mydomain.de
Front Door:The custom domain api.mydomain.de is mapped via a CNAME to Azure Front Door (mydomain-gateway-d5dnaahpgpe9axh6.z01.azurefd.net), which routes traffic to the APIM gateway (apim-name.azure-api.net).
DNS: A CNAME record exists for api.mydomain.de pointing to Front Door.
My goal:
I want to keep traffic flowing through Azure Front Door while using the custom domain api.mydomain.de in APIM.
When developers use the APIM Developer Portal, they should see api.mydomain.de as the API gateway URL (not the default APIM URL).
The problem:
When I try to add api.mydomain.de as a custom domain in APIM, it requires the CNAME to point directly to apim-name.azure-api.net. However, I want the CNAME to point to Azure Front Door (mydomain-gateway-d5dnaahpgpe9axh6.z01.azurefd.net) to benefit from Front Door features (like caching and global traffic routing).
What I’ve tried:
I’ve set up the DNS and routing rules in Front Door, which correctly forwards traffic to APIM.
I cannot proceed with adding api.mydomain.de as a custom domain in APIM without changing the CNAME, but I don't want to bypass Front Door.
Question: How can I configure APIM to use api.mydomain.de as a custom domain while still routing traffic through Azure Front Door? Is there a way to add the custom domain to APIM without changing the CNAME from Front Door to the APIM gateway?

could this be a valid solution: Temporarily add the CNAME pointing api.mydomain.de to APIM (just for the verification process). This is a short-lived change.
After Azure verifies the domain and allows you to add api.mydomain.de as a custom domain to APIM, revert the CNAME back to point to Front Door (mydomain-gateway-d5dnaahpgpe9axh6.z01.azurefd.net). ??


After Azure verifies the domain and allows you to add api.mydomain.de as a custom domain to APIM, revert the CNAME back to point to Front Door (mydomain-gateway-d5dnaahpgpe9axh6.z01.azurefd.net). ??

Yes, you can use the above approach temporarily to work around the domain verification requirement in Azure API Management.

Use a wildcard SSL certificate or custom SSL certificate that works across multiple subdomains (if not already done). When you upload this certificate to APIM, the custom domain will work even though the CNAME points to Azure Front Door.

Go to the Azure portal and navigate to the API Management instance. In API Management Service, go to Custom Domains under the Settings section.

Click + Add Custom Domain and enter api.mydomain.de.
Upload the SSL certificate for api.mydomain.de if prompted. Make sure you have an SSL certificate for the custom domain, as APIM requires this for the custom domain to work.


Update Frontdoor configuration, navigate to Azure Front Door instance.

Go to Routing Rules for api.mydomain.de and ensure traffic is being forwarded to the APIM backend (apim-name.azure-api.net).

In the routing rules, set the Backend Host Header to apim-name.azure-api.net. This checks that Azure Front Door forwards traffic correctly to APIM.
